# Custom view(collection view) Not Scrolling when using VoiceOver

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have custom view:

```
{CustomView () <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>}
```

I have set infinite scrolling in it.

However when I enable *voiceOver* it doesn't scroll.

I wish to select the entire view and scroll should take me from one cell to the next.

I can however use a 3 finger swipe to scroll if I make the individual cells as accessible elements and not the View itself.(This is not what I want)

Any idea how to go about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling collection view with cells being accessibility elements can be done by adding collection view to accessibility elements of its parent view like this:

```
// add to parent view:

Objc:
    [self setAccessibilityElements:@[self.collectionView]];

Swift:
    self.accessibilityElements = [collectionView]
```

Now if you keep swiping with one finger to right, voice over goes through all labels of first cell and once its done it automatically scrolls to another cell and goes through its labels etc..